# Meter contenido especifico de un ArrayList en un Array

Tags: java

tengo un ejercicio en el que quiero meter el contenido especifico de un ArrayList en un Array, el problema es el siguiente.

Tengo una clase que es Cuenta (refiriendose a cuenta del banco), otra clase llamada CuentaAhorro y otra que es CuentaCorriente (ambas son hijas de Cuenta poniendole el extends Cuenta).

Las cuentas las introduzco al arrancar el programa y son guardadas en un ArrayList, por lo que no es necesario contar el numero de Cuentas de Ahorro.

La opcion que tengo que codificar consiste en meter las cuentas de ahorro en un array; para ello estoy codificando un metodo del que llevo lo siguiente:

```
public static void arraycuentasahorro() {
        for (Cuentas c : arrayL) {
            if (c instanceof Cuentaahorro) {
                ahorro[0] = c;
            }
        }
    }
```

En este codigo, recorro el arrayList que contiene cuentas de ahorro y cuentas corrientes con un for mejorado y con un if, extraigo las cuentas de ahorro con un instanceof Cuentaahorro.

Hasta aquí, todo bien, mi problema ahora es que no se que es lo que tengo que introducir exactamente en el array, yo he puesto

ahorro[0]=c

pero se que esto no esta bien.

Alguien me puede decir que es lo que tengo que introducir en el array?

Graciasssss.

Comment: De que tipo es la variable ``ahorro``, qué es lo que deseas guardar en esa variable?, o Qué es lo quieres hacer, tal vez se puede mejorar el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes pasar un ArrayList a un Array directamente de esta forma:

```
Object[] ahorro = arrayL.toArray();
```

Luego podrías usar un cast.

Ahora siguiendo tu ejemplo podrías hacer esto:

```
CuentaAhorro[] ahorro = new CuentaAhorro[arrayL.size()];
  
        // ArrayList to Array Conversion
        for (int i=0;i<arrayL.size();i++){
            if (c instanceof Cuentaahorro) {
                ahorro[i] = c.get(i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, al final mi forma de resolverlo ha sido algo más rebuscada que la que tú pones aquí, he hecho una variable contador que se irá incrementando cada vez que añada una cuenta... Pero sin duda tu forma es la más correcta, muchas gracias